# Print out the maximum/minimum within a range in a list

Tags: python, list, range, max, min

I want to print out the maximum number between a number of values within a list. I also want to get the order of maximum number within the list. for example within `list_ = [1,3,5,6,7,2,3,6,4,3,5,7,8,11,10]`. The `maximum number is 11 at the 13th order in the list`. If the max happens more than once i would include the first order of index.

```
list_ = [1,3,5,6,7,2,3,6,4,3,5,7,8,11,10]
max = max(list[:len(list_)])
```

Comment: What if the maximum appears more than once? What would you report for the "order" / index?

Comment: @mhawke I would include the first order index of the max number. Good point, i will add that to the description.

Comment: What is the point of using a slice if the slice is the whole list?  Why not just `max(_list)`?

Comment: Also, naming your variable `max` replaces the `max()` function and you can't call it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
list_ = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 6, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 10, 11]

def func(lst):
    maxnum = max(lst)

    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == maxnum]

    print(maxnum, indices)


func(list_[3:6])
# prints: 7 [1]; 7 - maxnum, [1] - position in [3:6] list
```

where `maxnum` is the max number and `indices` are the indexes of `maxnum` if there is more.

Comment: what if I want to return values between one another like `list_[3:6]` to be returned.

Comment: If I understood correctly I'd just cover it into the function so you don't have to rewrite everything. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```py
max_num = max(list_)
max_num_index = list_.index(max_num)

print("The maximum number is {} at the {} order in the list".format(max_num, max_num_index))
```

Comment: what if I want to return values between one another like `list_[3:6]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
l = [1,3,5,6,7,2,3,6,4,3,5,7,8,11,10]
m=max(l)
print(f"max number is {m} at index {l.index(m,0)}")
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to search for a maximum value in a sub-list of a list and report it's position relative to the original list. This function does that and returns a tuple of `(max_value, position)`. The arguments `start` and `stop` should be considered as the upper and lower bounds on a slice:

```
def max_in_range(l, start=0, stop=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = len(l)

    m = max(l[start:stop])
    return (m, l.index(m, start, stop))


>>> l = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 6, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 10]
>>> max_in_range(l)
(11, 13)
>>> max_in_range(l, 14)        # start from index 14
(10, 14)
>>> max_in_range(l, stop=4)    # check from beginning to position 3
(6, 3)
>>> max_in_range(l, 3, 4)
(6, 3)
>>> max_in_range(l, 3, 5)
(7, 4)
>>> max_in_range(l, 3, 6)
(7, 4)
>>> max_in_range(l, 3, -2)     # can use negative indices
(8, 12)
```

There are some edge cases that you might like to handle in your code:

```
>>> max_in_range(l, 3, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in max_in_range
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```